# Идентификатор printf не определён

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Выполняю задание по алгоритмам компьютерной графики. В самом начале возник очередной затуп, так как 2 **printf** в коде [image: введите сюда описание изображения] выделяются как неопределённые идентификаторы. Не могу найти решение данной проблемы.

Comment: Никакой реакции. Добавил, сохранил, даже проект перезагрузил на всякий.

Comment: Не удалял. Что странно - её просто нет, как и stdio.h. Сейчас скачаю и отпишу.

Comment: Добавил. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Честно говоря, уже не знаю..

Comment: Что там "выделяется в коде" не имеет большого значения. Что говорит компиляция? Отдельно не ясно, что это за мешанина <c...> заголовков и <.h> заголовков.